# Quantity selector does not work in magento2

Tags: magento2, quantity

We have configured single products in grouped products. The quantity selector does not work with the minus and "+" signs.
See the Screen shot https://prnt.sc/ojpqi1

Comment: You are using some themes or etc. Can you please check in console and check if any error occur while you increase or decrease the quantity.? Or else check in the exception.log or system.log you will find issue.

Comment: @Mayur No errors are generated.

Answer (score 0):

As talked in comment without checking code I can not give you proper solution for your code.
But here is the one code you can check and it is tested code so it will help you from your issue.

[Magecomp Blog](https://magecomp.com/blog/add-quantity-increment-decrement-button-product-page-magento-2/)

Hope it will help you.

Thanks and regards

Comment: My code is proper. The same code works fine when i increment or decrement quantity for simple product. but it does not work when that product is added into a group. Is there any configuration need to be done for grouped products.